# Are both grammatically correct: "Our type of child…" OR "A child of our type…"

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

This is from a text on parenting the children with hyperactivity and attention deficiency disorders. [Parenting](https://www.additudemag.com/positive-parenting-extreme-child-discipline/)

> "***Our type of child*** *may respond more positively to praise than negative feedback*"

The part of the sentence **"Our type of child…"** sounds different to me. I would expect it to be **"A child of our type…"**.

Are both grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3):

They are both grammatically correct but do not make the same statements.  To say it as you have suggested would be to imply something different.

*"Our type of child . . ."* --> This suggests that the child is of the sort we like or understand.

*"A child of our type . . ."* --> This suggests that the child is like us.

The arrangement of the words makes a difference in how they are understood.  The way it was printed in the text is probably correct.